# Python unittest mock a function with optional default argument that may not be supplied

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock a function that looks like this [example]:

```
def f(overwrite=False):
    if overwrite:
        return "overwritten"
    else:
        return "skipping"
```

with a `unittest.mock.Mock` object that looks like this:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

mock_f = Mock(return_value = 'default', side_effect = lambda overwrite: 'overwrite' if overwrite else 'no overwrite')
#mock_f.func_defaults = (False,)
mock_f.__defaults__ = (False,)

mock_f()
```

The code above gives me an error (`TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'overwrite'`)

Since `f` itself can be called without supplying arguments, I need to be able to call `mock_f()` without arguments. However, if I try to call `mock_f(True)` or `mock_f(False)` it works fine. It doesn't work neither with `mock_f.func_defaults` nor with `mock_f.__defaults__`.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The side_effect has to have the same signature as the function it replaces, if used this way (e.g. if assigned a function object). That means that you have to adapt the side_effect, not the mock:

```py
>>> mock_f = Mock(return_value='default', side_effect=lambda
...               overwrite=False: 'overwrite' if overwrite else 'no overwrite')
>>> mock_f()

no overwrite
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wraps` to wrap `f`with a mock but still execute the real methods:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def f(overwrite=False):
    if overwrite:
        return "overwritten"
    else:
        return "skipping"


with patch('__main__.f', wraps=f) as mock_f:
    print(mock_f())
    print(mock_f(True))
    print(mock_f(False))
```

Output:

```
skipping
overwritten
skipping
```

Comment: Note: this is an alternative to @MrBean Bremen answer that is also right.